# Erro na animação Nightmare (Unity)

Tags: animação, unity3d, script

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

segui todos os passos, uso a nova versão da Unity, quando executo o jogo, a animação de andar n funciona ele fica andando sem a animação, quando passas uns segundos a animação começa a ser executada, mais para depois se eu parar de mover o player

Comment: "segui todos os passos"... Quais passos? Vc está seguindo algum tutorial? É importante citar qual, se for o caso. Edite a pergunta e poste também a parte do código em que você controla a animação, para que a comunidade possa ajudar se houver algum erro ali.

Comment: Além de colocar o que @Luiz Vieira orientou, poderia, por favor, mostrar a aba Parameters(você deixou marcada a Layer) e uma captura de tela dos transições de Idle para move e de move para Idle. Assim podemos ver se o código tem insumos para chamar.