# Não consigo fazer com que o personagem do nightmare desapareça depois de morto

Tags: c#, unity3d

Estou seguindo todos os passos de um tutorial sobre a criação do jogo Nightmare, vídeos feitos pelo canal "Jogando com Nils", mas depois de seguir todos os passos, quando executo o jogo e em seguida eu mato o *zombunny* (um inimigo), ao invés dele morrer e sumir do jogo, ele apenas fica parado na tela e aparece esse erro:

> 'Zombunny' AnimationEvent 'RestartLevel' has no receiver! Are you missing a component?

Alguém pode me ajudar a solucionar?

Comment: Pode editar sua pergunta e colocar o link para o tutorial?

Comment: Parece que o objeto do inimigo não tem um componente de código que precisaria ter pra receber o tal evento. Você já verificou isso? Além disso, faça como sugeriu o colega @CiganoMorrisonMendez: poste o vídeo do tutorial (e indique os minutos do vídeo onde essa parte é realizada). Se você não facilitar, ninguém vai ter interesse em te ajudar. P.S.: Isso também vale pra [sua outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/62742/erro-na-anima%C3%A7%C3%A3o-nightmare-unity).

Comment: Parece que o tutorial em português está aqui https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLa2bQ5uCFWA1RNqmaQIAWiq5HiWUGATyC, retirado do site do Unity http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/survival-shooter.

Comment: Só pra constar, outra pergunta foi criada com "potencialmente" o mesmo problema: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65331/erro-no-unity5-player-animationevent-restartlevel-has-no-receiver-are-you

Answer (score 1):

Tente destruir o objeto zombunny.

Coloque um if(se o zombunny morrer). Não sei se tem um script de vida no objeto.

```
Destroy(this.gameobject);
```

Este comando `destroy` faz o objeto desaparecer, caso tenha um script com essa linha.