# Problema com Desenvolvimento no Unity 5 3D

Tags: unity3d

Estou desenvolvendo um jogo usando o `Unity 5` e ao executar (dar play no jogo), aparece o seguinte erro e eu não estou conseguindo entendê-lo, eu acho que tem haver com algum processo negado, mas não sei o que é.

Ai está o erro:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Unity Projects\Jogo Nightmare\Temp\Assembly-CSharp.dll.mdb" is denied.

  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean isAsync, Boolean anonymous) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CompilerServices.SymbolWriter.MonoSymbolWriter.WriteSymbolFile (Guid guid) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.SymbolWriter+SymbolWriterImpl.WriteSymbolFile () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.SymbolWriter.WriteSymbolFile () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.CodeGen.Save (System.String name, Boolean saveDebugInfo, Mono.CSharp.Report Report) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Compile () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Se alguém souber por favor me fale.

Comment: Por acaso você tem algum antivírus rodando (talvez o McAfee)? Uma busca rápida no Google parece demonstrar que tem sido comum os antivírus barrerem o acesso a esse arquivo. [Fonte 1](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/internal-compiler-error-unhandled-exception-system-unauthorizedaccessexception.133493/). [Fonte 2](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/491473/internal-compiler-error-8.html). Talvez se você configurar o antivirus para adicionar esses arquivos como de confiança (*trustee*) resolva.

Comment: Luiz Vieira, eu tenho o McAfee instalado, mas eu não sabia que o problema seria ele, eu tava lendo as fontes que você me passou, e uma pessoa que tinha o mesmo problema que o meu, informou que, desabilitando a varredura em tempo real e o Firewall do windows resolveria o problema, mas com isso meu computador ficaria bastante vulnerável, sendo que eu não posso desinstalar pois tenho a versão paga dele. Você vê algum meio de eu resolver esse problema ? Desde já agradeço a sua ajuda.

Comment: Sim, foi o que eu sugeri: adicione o arquivo na lista de arquivos confiáveis do seu antivirus para ele parar de bloquear o acesso a esse arquivo. Eu não uso o McAfee, então não sei como faz isso nele. Mas se o problema é esse mesmo, esse tipo de configuração deve resolver. Aliás, se vc conseguir resolver com essa abordagem, por favor adicione você mesmo uma resposta detalhada aqui para ajudar outras pessoas no futuro. :)

Comment: Eu conseguir rodar ele desabilitando a opção varredura em tempo real, mas ao executar ele está aparecendo esse erro: " 'Player' AnimationEvent 'RestartLevel' has no receiver! Are you missing a component? " , você por um acaso, saberia o motivo desse erro ? Eu vou tentar procurar a opção de adicionar ele a lista de arquivos confiáveis e assim que eu conseguir, eu irei escrever uma resposta detalhada aqui.

Comment: Se é outro erro, abra outra pergunta. Aliás, [já tem uma pergunta sobre essa mensagem de erro](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/62847/n%C3%A3o-consigo-fazer-com-que-o-personagem-do-nightmare-desapare%C3%A7a-depois-de-morto), mas o autor não deu mais detalhes como solicitado...

Comment: Pronto. Vou dá uma olhada aqui, Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Com a ajuda do Luiz Vieira e dando uma pesquisada no Google, descobrir que esse erro é causado pelo anti vírus, no meu caso o McAfee que bloqueia o acesso ao arquivo, pois acha que está se tratando de uma invasão/vírus. Eu não conseguir adicionar uma lista confiável, e como eu não posso desinstala-lo, pois tenho a versão paga, a saída mais viável, é, desabilitar a varredura em tempo real, rodar seu jogo e assim que termina habilitar de novo ou se possível trocar o anti vírus. Mais uma vez muito obrigado pela ajuda Luiz Vieira.