# Erro no Unity5: "Player' AnimationEvent 'RestartLevel' has no receiver! Are you missing a component?"

Tags: unity3d

Boa noite.
Estou seguindo um tutorial de um jogo e quando eu o executo ele funciona, mas logo trava e aparece esse erro: "'Player' AnimationEvent 'RestartLevel' has no receiver! Are you missing a component?" , a única diferença que tem do meu jogo e o do tutorial, é que no meu aparece essa entidade ENTRY e no tutorial não aparece. Eu andei pesquisando e parece ser algo relacionado com a animação do player, mas eu não conseguir identificar o erro. Caso alguém souber responder, por favor me fale.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sua pergunta é praticamente a mesma [desta outra aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/62847/n%C3%A3o-consigo-fazer-com-que-o-personagem-do-nightmare-desapare%C3%A7a-depois-de-morto). Apesar de você ter colocado mais detalhes, ainda assim faltam informações pra alguém poder te ajudar. Qual é o tutorial? E o código onde você executa as animações, como está? Se você compartilhar o seu projeto (ou um [exemplo mínimo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) que reproduza o problema), fica muito mais fácil alguém ter interesse em testar e te ajudar.

Comment: Mas sabendo que se trata de algo envolvendo animação (na outra pergunta não dava pra saber disso), uma pesquisa mais detalhada no Google me retornou [essa thread no fórum da Unity](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/165763/anmationevent-has-no-receiver-error.html). Mas sem ver o seu código não dá pra dar alguma sugestão nesse sentido.

Comment: Ah, o `Entry` indica qual é o estado padrão da animação quando o objeto é criado/inicializado. Parece estranho que a máquina de estados de animação do seu objeto já comece no estado de "morte" (`Death`). Talvez a setinha do `Entry` devesse ser direcionada ao estado `Idle`, não? Não sei se o problema também decorre disso, mas vale o teste.

Answer (score 1):

Com [a ajuda do Luiz Vieira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65331/erro-no-unity5-player-animationevent-restartlevel-has-no-receiver-are-you#comment133748_65331) e olhando as fontes que ele me indicou, conseguir resolver o problema.

O problema era que a transição do estado ENTRY, que indica qual o estado padrão que a animação deve estar, estava conectado ao estado inicial errado. Foi só eu alterar a conexão dele do estado DEATH para o estado IDLE que o erro parou de ser apresentado.

Comment: Por nada. Fico feliz em ajudar. Mas você não precisa agradecer no texto da resposta, pois assim ela fica mais clara e objetiva. Eu a editei para tentar melhorar (se não gostar de algo, é só desfazer a edição). Aliás, pra ficar ainda mais claro para outros usuários que no futuro podem ter a mesma dúvida, eu sugeriria você editar a resposta para incluir um screenshot com a nova máquina de estados após a sua correção (não precisa ser da tela inteira, só da máquina de estados da animação). Depois que fizer isso, eu excluo este meu comentário. :)